# Unable to Push key value pair in an Array in a $.each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to Push key-value pair in an Array in a loop.

```
var arr_ReservationType = new Array();
$("#table tr").each(function()
{
    arr_ReservationType=
  { 
    key: "value"
  }
});
```

I have also tried

```
arr_ReservationType[index].push({key:"value"});
```

and

```
 arr_ReservationType[index].push({key:"value"});
    index++;
 });
```

But all these codes are adding an object to the array, not the key-value pair.

I am not able to find the exact solution to my problem. 
Please suggest if there is a similar solution available or any alternate solution. Thanks.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ReservationTypeName] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ReservationTypeName] => 123
        )

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript You can't directly push key:value pair in array like other languages. U need to push objects in an array with key:value pair like this **arr_ReservationType.push({key:"value"});**.

It's possible only through array of objects.

Comment: then to retrieve that in php , i need to loop in nested array , is there any alternate ?

Comment: Yeah...U can do it. If it nested then again u have to create an array inside array keep pushing objects..

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do `arr_ReservationType.push({key:"value"});` as `arr_ReservationType` is your array and it will add the value in the array.

You code will be something like this:

```
$('#table tr').each(function () {
  arr_ReservationType.push({
    key: 'value'
  });
});
```

Comment: showing Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ReservationTypeName] => 123
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ReservationTypeName] => 123
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

you need to push your data in the array as

```
var arr_ReservationType = new Array();
$("#table tr").each(function(){
    arr_ReservationType.push({key:"value"});
})
```